# Fixing coefficient with error for fit

Tags: regression, curve-fitting, uncertainty

Suppose I believe my data set {{x,y}} is well described by $y = a_2x^2+a_1x + a_0$ (or some more general function $f(x,a_0....a_n)$. I would like to carry out a fit to estimate the coefficients, and the uncertainties on them. But I have already measured, say, $a_1$ using a different method. I would therefore like to fix $a_1$. However, if I do this naively by simply setting it to the measured value, I am ignoring the experimental error on my direct measurement of $a_1$, which must surely propagate through to the uncertainty on the estimates of $a_0, a_2...a_n$.

How do I handle this properly? I'm using Python and Scipy, but I think my question is more about the maths.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With data $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_k,y_k),...,(x_n,y_n)$
$$y_k=a_2(x_k)^2+a_1x_k+a_0+\epsilon_k \tag 1$$
Now $a_1$ is known with some uncertainity. Let :
$$Y_k=y_k-a_1x_k$$
Then, with the respective ranges of uncertainities on $y_k$ , on $x_k$ and on $a_1$ I suppose that you know the range of uncertainity on $Y_k$.

$$Y_k=a_2(x_k)^2+a_0+\epsilon'_k \tag 2$$
This is exactly the same problem of regression than for Eq.$(1)$. In solving it on the same manner, the uncertainity on $a_1$ are taken into account via the combined uncertainities on $Y_k$.

Comment: This is a really useful answer, but in the end I used a Monte Carlo approach to assess the probability distribution of the coefficients.